# Showing a $2\times2$ matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let ${A}$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix. For every two-dimensional vector ${v}$, there exists a two-dimensional vector ${w}$ such that
${A} {w} = {v}.$
Show that ${A}$ is invertible.

I have no idea on how to start this, but I have a hint:

Which two vectors ${v}$ are we most interested in if we are trying to find the matrix ${B}$ such that ${A}{B}= {I}$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Viewing $A$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is surjective. Have you seen the rank nullity theorem for matrices?

Comment: The rank-nullity theorem is overkill for this.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Let $v_1$, $v_2$ be  column vectors of $I$ (identity matrix).

Comment: Nice, that's a slick way. Couldn't think of something that clever fast.

Comment: I don't see how this helps. Also, what are $v_1$ and $v_2$? Which matrix and how does that help. Thanks

Comment: I bashed my way though by plugging in variables for each. So far, I have the following from the fact that $\mathbf{AB} = \mathbf{I} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ where $\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c  & d \end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{B} = \begin{pmatrix}e & f \\ g & h\end{pmatrix}$:
\begin{align*}
ac+bg&=cf+dh &= 1 \\
ce+dg&=af+bh &= 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: In addition, I have $\mathbf{Aw} = \mathbf{v} \longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c  & d \end{pmatrix} \dbinom{m}{n} =\dbinom{x}{y}.$ From this I get, 
\begin{align*}
am+bn &= x \\
cm+dn &= y.
\end{align*}
Since, B is the inverse, we also get $\mathbf{Bv} = \mathbf{w}\longrightarrow  \begin{pmatrix}e & f \\ g  & h \end{pmatrix} \dbinom{x}{y} = \dbinom{m}{n}.$ From this I get, 
\begin{align*}
ex+fy &= m \\
gx+hy &= n.
\end{align*}